# Iphone SDK how to save my score?

Tags: iphone

i have a integer called HighScore which is connected to highscorelabel . i have made it so when the user gets a high score it puts the score they got onto the label but i would now like to know how i can save it so that when the app is opened again it will still have the high score : this is my code for detecting when a high score is made

```
 (void) submitScore {
if (lives > HighScore){
 HighScore = lives;
}
highscorelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , HighScore];
}
```

Comment: dave, please don't reply to your question with answer after answer. If you have more information to add, do it as an edit to your original post or as a comment to your post, or as a comment to an answer, where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSUserDefaults for saving:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[prefs setInteger:HighScore  forKey:@"HighScore "];

[prefs synchronize];
```

and retrieving:

```
HighScore  = [prefs integerForKey:@"HighScore"];
```